# Best way to zero all the elements of the struct

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a struct that I frequently use in my code which is :

```
struct HttpResponse{

string header;
string response;
int statusCode;

HttpResponse():header(""),response(""),statusCode(0){}
HttpResponse(string header,string response,int statusCode):header(header),response(response),statusCode(statusCode){}
};
```

I need to make sure that all the strings are initialized to "" and the integer to (0) . Creating the struct each time I need it with default constructor or creating it once and zero all its members after each use are the options that I can see . Which approach would be more efficient ?

Comment: Use the constructor, that's what they're for.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding the question.  Can you show how you are using it?

Comment: I can either create a new object in every class function like HttpResponse responseObject;  or make the struct a class member variable and call another function to zero all the values after each time I use the struct, because , I dont want any leftover values from previous uses.

Comment: Structs in C++ are classes. Use them as you would use classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this depends on a few things. So you will have to benchmark both implementations with your program using reasonable benchmarking input.

There are some general considerations to be made, however:

First of all, constructing and deleting strings can be somewhat costly because it may involve allocating and deallocating memory on the heap. It is not extremely costly however and depends on the implementation. I would expect keeping around a "Response" object to be slightly faster.

On the other hand, keeping around such cached objects has potential disadvantages:

1. You may forget to call clear, and create a bug that is hard to find.
   This depends on how many different uses of cached responses are there in the code.
2. References to your cached object may escape and be stored longer than you thought or your program becomes multithreaded, which can lead to unexpected aliasing and even worse bugs.
3. Using a local static response means that a (probably quite efficient) check for initialization may be added at the start of the function.
4. Using a cached response passed in by a pointer (explicitly or implicitly as a member of an object via the this pointer) may make the compiler's alias analysis more cautious and prevent other optimizations. The compiler may also be prevented from eliminating unused computations on a temporary response when all code is inlined.

Of these potential disadvantages I would only worry about 1 and 2 at first and only consider the others when profiling proves they may be relevant.

One other step I would recommend if the code proves to be critical is to look at the code being generated:

https://godbolt.org/g/SFCc23

One thing I learned here is that with gcc it is more efficient to initialize a string with the default constructor which makes it empty than to use `string("")`

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

struct HttpResponse{

string header;
string response;
int statusCode;

HttpResponse():header(),response(),statusCode(0){}
HttpResponse(string header,string response,int statusCode):header(header),response(response),statusCode(statusCode){}
void clear()
{
    header.clear();
    response.clear();
    statusCode = 0;
}
};

void handleResponse(HttpResponse &r);

void test()
{
    HttpResponse r;
    handleResponse(r);
}

void test2()
{
    static HttpResponse r;
    r.clear();

    handleResponse(r);
}

void test3(HttpResponse *theCachedResponse)
{
    theCachedResponse->clear();
    handleResponse(*theCachedResponse);
}
```

In this case the code generated for the third variant looks somewhat shorter than the code for the other variants. Note that `test2` will only take the long initialization path once, so the test and jump at the start will be predicted excellently by even the worst branch predictors and therefore hardly take time on a larger CPU. If the function is called repeatedly the initialization will not be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The normal thing to do is to build a default constructor if necessary. It is necessary in your case since otherwise `statusCode` will remain uninitialised. (The `std::string` constructors will be called for you).

`HttpResponse() : statusCode(0){}` will be sufficient.

You could build yourself some kind of `clear` method; but that will necessitate your having to consider all the class members, not just the plain old data types. That's more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

As Bathsheba said use the default constructor. If and only if you face performance problems (and you can prove that using a profiler) you can optimise this. Please do not optimise prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I disagree with my colleagues above. You should not deallocate and reallocate memory just to reset the state of a class. It's terribly inefficient. For what you are asking, i.e. is it more efficient to destroy-and-recreate or to use a "clear" method? I think the clear answer is the second

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer to this problem is to use the constructor, create the struct each time is needed. Because the other solution is "premature optimization".

But, the second variant could be better, and I don't consider it as premature optimization. It is not harder to write, not harder to understand, not harder to maintain. Just a different solution (which may have its shortcomings. For example, it cannot be used in multi-threaded environment).

Why could the second variant be better? Because you could avoid memory allocation/free for your strings (current implementations don't free memory for `string::clear`, so you'll avoid unnecessary memory operations, if the strings don't grow).